# Can someone use an alias in a covenant not to sue that refers to the signing person?

Tags: contract-law

Take the following scenario:

- a party wants a company to sign a covenant not to sue where they agree not to sue me
- The company doesn't know the party's name (yet)
- the party does not want the company to know their name as long as they have not agreed not to sue them

Could someone use an alias in the covenant covenant not to sue, and then say that it refers to the person that has signed the covenant not to sue ?
This way, the person has the company sign the covenant not to sue paper first. Then the person signs it too and adds the party's name. This means that as soon as the person has signed the agreement, the company will know the person's name but will also not be allowed to sue the person.

Comment: Other ideas I have, encrypt a message (e.g my name) with PGP in the contract. If they try to sue me later, decrypt the message showing I am the one they are not allowed to sue. Would that have any weight in court ?

Comment: I assume there is some dispute pending or you would not be looking for this agreement . The potential grounds of the suit would presumably be in the agreement so they are not giving person X a blank check. Why would a company agree to enter into to something like this - what do they get out of it? This seems very strange.

Comment: I know confidential information about the company. They want me to sign an NDA so that I do not release this informations. Signing this NDA imply for me to reveal my identity, which is why I first want to sign a covenant not to sue. @GeorgeWhite
Note : I am not an employee of the company or affiliated to it in anyway.

Comment: They do not know who you are but they would like you to sign an NDA? Even stranger.  How would they know if the unknown person they want to sign an NDA did or didn't sign it?

Comment: The NDA will contain my real name since I plan to reveal it once the covenant not to sue has been signed.

Comment: An NDA says party X can't disclose  secret Y of party Z. If they do party Z sues them. An NDA that said party Z didn't have that remedy would need some other remedy or it would be a pointless document

Comment: voting to close as asking for legal advice.- get a lawyer

Comment: I disagree. I think my question is open enough to be applicable in numerous other cases and to help others.

Comment: I think the only effective way is to have a legal representative approach the company.